# Measuring pulse using an EMG device

Tags: arduino, sensor, measurement, biopotential

For another project I once bought the following EMG sensor kit: 
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11776

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to measure the heart pulse using that EMG sensor and an Arduino board?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physiology and not about electronic design.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Aaaaamm... in my opinion, Not completely! I guess he want to ensure that his choices are correct. not bad

Comment: This is not about physiology.  It is about electronics used to measure physiological activity.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible, but the heart signal is generally processed differently than the EMG signal.  The EMG signal is much higher frequency than the ECG signal in their raw forms.  The general way to process EMG (which is muscle activity) is to high-pass filter, then rectify, then low pass filter to recover the envelope of the signal.

In fact, the [schematic](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/Muscle%20Sensor%20Platinum%20v3.3.pdf)  for the product you link to shows just that.

The problematic stage will likely be the high pass filtering, which will likely wipe out the "heart pulse".  The rectification won't help, either.

I'm not sure what you mean by "arduino board".  Is this just an Arduino?  You might find an Arduino shield that you can plug your electrodes into that will work, but if you mean you'd like to plug the output of that board you link to into an analog input on an Arduino, that probably won't work well.

Long story short, that product will not provide useful information about the heart beat.